# I am going to my parents or I will go to tomorrow

Tags: will-vs-going-to

I am going to my parents or I will go to tomorrow
What is the right one? Why?

Answer (score 1):

both are correct, but if you don't add any context if you said

> I am going to my parents

I would expect it to be very soon, or you are already on the journey.